# jquery change button state on click

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am working on Yii2 application which has one submit button, as below

```
<button id="next" class="btn btn-primary btn-submit " data-loading-text="Please wait, processing..." value="1" name="next" type="submit">
```

When I click the button, it is disabled and the text changes, as below

```
<button id="next" class="btn btn-primary btn-submit disabled" data-loading-text="Please wait, processing..." value="1" name="next" type="submit" disabled="disabled">Please wait, processing...</button>
```

Now I have added one text field with required attributes, as below

```
<input id="name" class="form-control" type="text"maxlength="255" required="required"  title="">
```

My issue is that when I click on the submit button when the text field is empty, it shows me that field is required but at he same time the button becomes disabled.

How do I return this button to its original enabled state if the text field is empty?

Comment: It's nothing to do with yii.

Answer (score 0):

You should use both `removeAttr('disabled')` and `removeClass('disabled')`

Try the below approach.

```js
$name = $('#name');
$next = $('#next');
$next.on('click', function() {
  $(this).addClass('disabled').attr('disabled', 'disabled').text($(this).data('loading-text'));

  // Your work here

})

$name.on('input', function() {
  changeState($(this));
})
changeState($name);

function changeState(elem) {
  if (elem.val().trim().length) {
    $next.removeClass('disabled').removeAttr('disabled');
  } else {
    $next.addClass('disabled').attr('disabled', 'disabled').text('Next');
  }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input id="name" class="form-control" type="text" maxlength="255" required="required" title="">
<button id="next" class="btn btn-primary btn-submit " data-loading-text="Please wait, processing..." value="1" name="next" type="submit">Next</button>
```

Comment: Hi @Prs thanks for reply, but how to findout when use these attributes , like when field is empty then only use these else it will prcoess the form.